# iOS Navigation Bar title truncated on segue

Tags: ios, iphone, uisplitviewcontroller

I just started implementing a Split View Controller for my iOS app, trying to make the storyboard universal. Most things seem to work fine although on iPhone I get this weird issue in the navigation bar on push:

[image: ios navigation bar title truncated on replace]

I set the title with the simple `self.title = "Shoulders"`.

Here's what the storyboard looks like:

[image: Split View Storyboard]

I tried to recreate the connections, but the problem is the same. Works fine on iPad. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Show the code where you set the title

Comment: @azimov it happens in the viewDidLoad method, with a simple self.title = "shoulders".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up fixing it by setting the title on the master view's `prepareForSegue()`. Works like a charm.